# Are there size restrictions when profiling a PDF?

Tags: watson-knowledge-catalog

When I try to profile a pdf, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work. Are there size limitations on what can be profiled in Watson Knowledge Catalog?

Answer (score 0):

Watson Knowledge Catalog uses the Watson Natural Language Understanding service to profile unstructured data which has a limit of 50,000 characters.

Here's some additional info you may find helpful:
- https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/371347/how-to-use-natural-language-understanding-service/

If the profiling service is not working intermittently for some reason, we might need to look further.  You can open a support ticket for our support team to investigate (Support > Manage Tickets), especially if the same PDF fails to profile every time on multiple tries.

However, if the same PDF is getting profiled sometimes but not getting profiled other times, then it's likely a temporary cloud service issue.